# Confusion about Transformation of Spin-Weighted Functions

Tags: general-relativity, spinors

**Short version:**
I'm trying to understand spin-weighted spherical functions. Wikipedia defines them as functions of a point $\textbf{x}$ on the sphere and an orthonormal frame $\textbf{a}$, $\textbf{b}$ at $\textbf{x}$ such that
$$
f\left(\textbf{x}, \cos\psi \,\textbf{a} - \sin\psi \,\textbf{b}, \sin\psi \,\textbf{a} + \cos\psi \,\textbf{b}\right) = e^{i s \psi}
f\left(\textbf{x}, \textbf{a}, \textbf{b}\right)
$$
for all angles $\psi$. It is conventional to define a complex vector
$$ \textbf{m} = \frac{\textbf{a} + i\textbf{b}}{\sqrt{2}}.$$
so that we can write
$$
f\left(\textbf{x}, \textbf{m}'\right) = e^{i s \psi}
f\left(\textbf{x}, \textbf{m}\right),$$
where $\textbf{m}' = e^{i \psi}\textbf{m}$. It is also conventional to take $\textbf{m} = \frac{\widehat{\boldsymbol{\theta}} + i\widehat{\boldsymbol{\phi}} }{\sqrt{2}}$.

Choosing the usual coordinates on the sphere, we can then define the operator
$$\eth_s \eta = -\left(\sin\theta\right)^s 
\left(\partial_\theta + \frac{i}{\sin\theta} \partial_\phi 
\right) \left(\left(\sin\theta\right)^{-s} \eta\right).$$
I am then told that this operator raises the spin weight of a function, i.e., if $\eta$ has spin weight $s$, so $\eta' = e^{is\psi} \eta$, then
$$ (\eth_s \eta)' = e^{i(s+1)\psi} \eth_s \eta.$$
**How can I show this?** Clearly the $\eth_s$ operator is affected by the rotation of $\textbf{m}$, but I don't quite see how. My understanding is that the rotation of $\textbf{m}$ isn't equivalent to an ordinary transformation of coordinates.

**Longer Version:**

The first paper to introduce spin-weighted functions is ["Note on the Bondi-Metzner-Sachs Group"](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1931221) by Newman and Penrose. In this work they introduce the complex coordinate $\zeta = e^{i\phi} \cot\frac{\theta}{2}$ via stereographic projection. They then note that in this coordinate system, "the natural choice for $\textbf{m}$ is to make $\text{Re}\left[\textbf{m}\right]$ and $\text{Im}\left[\textbf{m}\right]$ tangential, respectively, to the curves $\text{Im}\left[\zeta\right] = \text{const.}$ and $\text{Re}\left[\zeta\right] = \text{const.}$" I see that this will induce a rotation of $\textbf{m}$ by $-\phi$ when moving from the sphere down to the complex $\zeta$ plane, but I don't understand how to use this. They then proceed to write
$$\eth_s\eta = 2 P^{1-s}\frac{\partial}{\partial\zeta}\left(P^s \eta\right),$$
where
$$P = \frac{1}{2}\left(1+ \zeta\overline{\zeta}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\csc^2\frac{\theta}{2}.$$ It then appears that they define a transformed coordinate $\zeta' = e^{-i\psi}\zeta$. Since $P' = P$, it quickly follows that
$$ (\eth_s \eta)' 
= 2 P^{1-s}\frac{\partial}{\partial\zeta'}\left(P^s \eta'\right)
= 2 P^{1-s}e^{i\psi}\frac{\partial}{\partial\zeta}\left(P^s e^{is\psi}\eta\right)
= e^{i(s+1)\psi}\eth_s \eta.$$
I have multiple questions about this process.

1. Why is $\zeta' = e^{-i\psi} \zeta$? I think see how a counter-clockwise rotation of $\textbf{m}$ on the sphere induces a clockwise rotation of the same $\textbf{m}$ on the complex plane, since $\widehat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}$ always points in the negative $z$ direction on the sphere, which maps to the negative radial direction in the complex $\zeta$ plane. But don't Newman and Penrose say that when working with $\zeta$ a different convention for $\textbf{m}$ is chosen?
2. How does this extra rotation of $-\phi$ between the two conventions for $\textbf{m}$ affect $\eth_s$ in spherical coordinates? It must, because the two expressions for $\eth_s$ don't agree if I just plug in
   $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta} = -e^{-i\phi} \sin^2\frac{\theta}{2} \, \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} - \frac{i}{2} e^{-i\phi} \tan \frac{\theta}{2} \, \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}.$$
3. If I want to perform the rotation of $\textbf{m}$ on $\eth_s \eta$ without using complex coordinates, how do I do that?
4. Why do Newman and Penrose implement the rotation of $\textbf{m}$ via a simple change of coordinates from $\zeta$ to $\zeta'$? Isn't a rotation of the frame distinct from a change of coordinates? In my mind the rotation of $\textbf{m}$ rotates each frame at each point on the sphere by $\psi$, but doesn't change the points themselves.
5. Bonus question: I've seen multiple sources refer to $\eth_s$ as essentially the covariant derivative on the sphere. How is this true?